# TIBCO Spotifre Analyst v7.10: Delete Rows That Have Blank / Null Value in Column

Tags: null, conditional-statements, spotfire

I have the following table / report in Spotfire.  I want to delete / remove all rows that are null (don't have value) in the "Value" column.

```
Id      Date        cDate       Value         
--------------------------------------------
A       10/17/2017  10/18/2017     1               
A       10/17/2017  10/14/2017         
A       10/17/2017  10/8/2017             
B       11/19/2017  11/19/2017     1      
B       11/19/2017  11/30/2017
```

I DO NOT want to filter for Value = 1 to achieve the above.  The goal is to delete unnecessary rows.

Is this possible to do in Spotfire?

I want the resulting table /report to look like this:

```
Id      Date        cDate       Value         
--------------------------------------------
A       10/17/2017  10/18/2017     1                        
B       11/19/2017  11/19/2017     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spotfire does not manage your data for you. what you're asking isn't possible.

you have listed the solution there, however, which is to filter out rows that do not contain `[Value]` of 1. you can use either the **Filters Panel** or a **Data Limiting Expression** to accomplish this. if that doesn't solve your issue, please provide more information about why you think you need to physically delete the rows.

---

**EDIT**

with the extra info, there's a bit of a hacky solution you can use. again I will stress that the correct way to solve this problem is at the data level; Spotfire is not here to manage your data, rather to help make sense of it :)

but you can reproduce the results you want for the data set you posted by adding a pivot transformation (**Insert**»**Transformations...**, then choose **Pivot**) configured like in this screenshot:

[image]

once you've pivoted to eliminate the other rows, you'll be able to join columns as you like.

**NOTE**: *this may not work in a larger data set!* it depends on what you're doing with the dates. you can play around with the aggregation (e.g., using `Last()` rather than `First()`) but, and sorry to harp on it, this isn't the right way to solve this problem.

Comment: thank you; I'm trying to merge the above table into another report / table ... I don't want to merge all the rows in --> I only want to merge in the rows that have 1 in "value" ; any suggestions for this?

Comment: when you say "merge" what do you mean by that? I ask because "merging" isn't really something Spotfire does

Comment: sorry that it took me a few days, but see if my edited answer suits your needs